# "Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference" possibly related to number types problem. How do I change my number types?

Tags: fortran, gfortran, fortran90

I am trying to use an old Fortran code for processing data.  I have little experience with Fortran and have been unable to get past a problem that I think is to do with number types.

Part of the code I am using is at the bottom of this question.  I am pretty sure, but not certain, that the second-last line (also the second-last line of this post) is the problem.

First I did this:

```
gfortran -g cpt_ir_.f90 -o cpt_ir_.o
./cpt_ir_.o < di.in
```

It resulted in this error:

```
Backtrace for this error:
#0  0x2B794A134467
#1  0x2B794A134AAE
#2  0x2B794ABC724F
#3  0x2B794A1FB8AB
#4  0x2B794A1F7613
#5  0x2B794A1F934E
#6  0x2B794A1FDF86
#7  0x40128A in MAIN__ at cpt_ir_.f90:29
Segmentation fault
```

I searched Stack Overflow and saw a suggestion to do the following to get more information:

```
gfortran -g -fcheck=all -Wall cpt_ir_.f90
```

The output is shown directly below.  The Fmax... line is the final line of the code I pasted at the end of this post (further in the code there are other similar lines).  However, I see that it is shown as a warning, not an error.  So I although I proceed here as though it is *the* error, maybe there is another problem that the command above did not reveal.

```
cpt_ir_.f90:66.5:
Fmax=N*((4000.0/(2.0*Pi))*(2.0*Pi*timestep*1.0-15.0*29979245800.0))
     1
Warning: Possible change of value in conversion from REAL(8) to INTEGER(4) at (1)
```

I came across a suggestion here at Stack Overflow to use the following flags:

```
-fdefault-integer-8 -fno-range-check
```

Which I did as follows:

```
gfortran -g -fdefault-integer-8 -fno-range-check cpt_ir_.f90 -o cpt_ir_.o
```

I'm not sure if I did it correctly.  I also tried them one by one.  Anyway, there was no change and I got the same error.  I also tried manually changing the numbers in the problem line as shown in the final line of this post.  That didn't help either--I got an error that the largest number was too large for an int.

If anyone could please point me in the right direction, I would be very grateful.  Please also feel free to change my tags if there are more appropriate tags for this question.

**cpt_ir_.f90:**

```
!
!
IMPLICIT NONE
INTEGER, PARAMETER :: dp=KIND(0.0D0)
REAL(KIND=dp), DIMENSION(:), ALLOCATABLE :: correlation
REAL(KIND=dp) :: integral,omega,Pi,timestep
REAL(KIND=dp), DIMENSION(3,1000000) :: dipder,dip
REAL(KIND=dp), DIMENSION(3) :: m_vec 
INTEGER :: N,I,J,Nmax,Fmax
CHARACTER(LEN=100) :: line,filename

Pi=4.0D0*ATAN(1.0D0)

READ(5,*) filename
READ(5,*) timestep

OPEN(10,FILE=filename)
N=0
DO 
 READ(10,'(A100)',END=999) line
 IF (INDEX(line,' XXX').NE.0) THEN
    N=N+1
    READ(line(45:),*) dip(:,N)
 ENDIF
 IF (INDEX(line,' XXX').NE.0) THEN
    N=N+1
    READ(line(45:),*) dipder(:,N)
 ENDIF
ENDDO
999 CONTINUE

CLOSE(10)

Nmax=N/10

print *, Nmax

ALLOCATE(correlation(0:Nmax))
correlation=0.0_dp

DO I=1,N-Nmax
 DO J=I,I+Nmax
    correlation(J-I)=correlation(J-I)+DOT_PRODUCT(dipder(:,I),dipder(:,J))
 ENDDO
ENDDO

DO I=0,Nmax
   correlation(I)=correlation(I)/(REAL(N-I,kind=dp)*REAL(N,kind=dp))
ENDDO

OPEN(UNIT=10,FILE="dip_dip_correlation.time")
write(10,*) "XXX"
DO I=-Nmax,Nmax
   write(10,*) I*timestep,correlation(ABS(I))/correlation(0)
ENDDO
CLOSE(10)

OPEN(UNIT=10,FILE="XXX")
write(10,*) "XXX"
!Fmax up to 4000 cm^-1
Fmax=N*((4000D0/(2*Pi))*(2.0D0*Pi*timestep*1.0D-15*29979245800.0))   
! My try: Fmax=N*((4000.0/(2.0*Pi))*(2.0*Pi*timestep*1.0-15.0*29979245800.0))
```

---

Update based on Dan's answer:
Dan kindly pointed out that I needed to uncomment "N=N+1."  Unfortunately, after fixing that, I am still seeing the segmentation fault.  Just now when I ran:

```
gfortran -g -fcheck=all -Wall cpt_ir_.f90
```

on my try at the last line of the code (where I tried converting everything to a float):

Fmax=N*((4000.0/(2.0*Pi))*(2.0*Pi*timestep*1.0-15.0*29979245800.0))

I got:

```
Fmax=N*((4000.0/(2.0*Pi))*(2.0*Pi*timestep*1.0-15.0*29979245800.0))
         1
Warning: Possible change of value in conversion from REAL(8) to INTEGER(4) at (1)
```

Comment: Fmax is an integer. Provided it is what you want to do, you can disregard the warning. You can do thevconversion explicit using `int()`. If it is not what you want to do, make `Fmax` a real variable.

Comment: Did you run the program again after compiling with those checking options?  The warning you point to is a _compile time_ warning, whereas the segmentation fault is a _run time_ error.  The two needn't be related.

Comment: @francescalus, thank you.  I'm embarrassed--it has been a while since I had to compile anything and did forget that step!  However, I did recompile (with no problem) and re-run and am still getting the segmentation fault, unfortunately.  I just can't figure out where it is coming from.

Answer (score 1):

At a glance, your line

```
READ(line(45:),*) dip(:,N)
```

is the first problem. You comment out the `N=N+1` line so N = 0. Fortran is '1' indexed meaning that Fortran arrays start at 1 unless otherwise specified. So the second dimension of dip starts at 1 and you are trying to set the 'zeroth' element which does not exist.

Comment: Thank you very much for catching that, Dan!  Unfortunately, I'm still getting the segmentation fault and the "gfortran -g -fcheck=all -Wall cpt_ir_.f90" command is still telling me this: Warning: Possible change of value in conversion from REAL(8) to INTEGER(4) at (1). I'll update the question based on your advice though.

Comment: We can glance and guess and give suggestions. But to really help you chase this down, can you give us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with a sample data set that has the problem. Complete means all the way from 'program' to 'end program'.